# Expectation (and concentration?) for $\min(X, n-X)$ when $X$ is a Binomial

Tags: probability, reference-request, binomial-distribution

I'd like to know if some results are known on the following type of random variables: for parameter $p\in[0,1]$ (for my purposes, $p < \frac{1}{2}$, and even $p \ll 1$) and $n \geq 1$, we let $X$ be a random variable following a Binomial$(n,p)$ distribution, and define $$Y \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \min(X, n-X).$$

Then, as a function of $p$ and $n$: what is the distribution of $Y$? In particular, what is its expectation $\mathbb{E}[Y]$, and what are the best concentration bounds one can obtain around $\mathbb{E}[Y]$? (Does anything like Hoeffding/Chernoff hold?)

---

As a small remark: for the range of $p$  I am interested in, we should have $\mathbb{E}[Y] \approx \mathbb{E}[X] = pn$, since the probability that $X > \frac{n}{2}$ is exponentially small (in $n$). Big discrepancies between $X$ and $Y$ should only appear when $pn\in [n/2-O(\sqrt{n}), n]$, and for $p$ outside this range $X$ and $Y$ should have distributions *very* close (in total variation distance). But is there (a) an exact expression for $\mathbb{E}[Y]$, or one that holds even for moderately small $n$? and (b) good concentration bounds for $Y$?

For instance, for $n=2$ we get the exact value $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 2p(1-p) = 2p + O(p^2)$, and for $n=3$ we obtain $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 4p + O(p^3)$.

Comment: For even $n$: $EY_{n}=EX_n-2E(X_n-\frac n 2; X_n>\frac n 2)$. The last term is $$(p(1-p))^{n/2}\sum_{i\ge 1}ir^i\binom n{n/2+i}$$

If $n^{1/2}(\frac 1 2-p)$ is large ($\omega(1)$ asymptotically), the binomial can be approximated as constant and further approximated through CLT/Stirling's to get a good approximation/upper bound. If $n$ is small but $p\ll 1$, keep the first term only to get a reasonable lower bound. Similarly, $P(Y_n\ge an)=P(X_n\ge an)-2P(X_n>(1-a)n)$ and approximate similarly. See http://bit.ly/1Us5NuB for better-than-Chernoff asymptotics of large deviations for binomial.

Comment: Thank you -- I'll see if that does the job for my purposes (as usual, the end goal of my question and the question itself are related, but I'm always losing something in between...)

Comment: You gotta start spilling the beans then because without it, there are not enough hints to know which way to go deeper. I sketched extension to general $n^{1/2}(\frac 1 2-p)=C$ but it didn't get saved. Don't know how to address small or moderate $n$. Might hold for moderate $n$ as well.

Comment: @A.S. More details: what I am looking for is, in short, the following: what is a harp asymptotic expression the expected value of the "minimum influence" of a randomly chosen Boolean function $f\colon\{0,1\}^n\to \{0,1\}$, when $f$ is generated by choosing each of its $2^n$ values independently at random from a Bernoulli$(p)$ (where $p=p(n)$ is small, either $o(1)$ or a small constant).

Comment: The "minimum influence" $\min_{i\in[n]} \operatorname{Inf}_f(i)$ is defined from $ \operatorname{Inf}_f(i)$, the number of points $x\in\{0,1\}$ such that flipping the $i$-th bit of $x$ changes the value of $f$ (i.e., $f(x)neq f(x)\neq f(x^{(i)})$, where $x^{(i)}$ is $x$ with the $i$-th bit flipped). So the goal is to characterize $\mathbb{E}_f[\min_{i\in[n]} mathbb{P}_x\{f(x)\neq f(x^{(i)}\} ] ]$.

Comment: @A.S. If you want, I can give you a bit more on what I attempted...